# How to create bean with custom BeanName in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

**Problem**

There is a `Processor` class which processes something based on its `typesToProcess`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Processor {

    private String typesToProcess;

    public Processor(String typesToProcess) {
        this.typesToProcess = typesToProcess;
    }

    public void process(String type) {
        if (typesToProcess.equals(type)) {
            // process
        }
    }
}
```

I need to create some `Processor` instances to work at different places. The problem is I don't know how many `Processor` instances should be created when the Spring Application is bootstrapping, as well as their 'typesToProcess'. Further more, the number of `Processor` instances might change when the application is running. I need to read the types from some configuration file which is stored in database periodically.

**Attempts**

One way to solve this problem I can thing out is using `typesToProcess` + `Processor` as the bean name, though I know it wont work. Is there any other way?

```
import com.meituan.picture.selection.processor.impl.Processor;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ProcessorContainer implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public Processor getProcessor(String type) {
        String realBeanName = "processor" + type;
        // obviouslly this wont work
        return applicationContext.getBean(realBeanName, Processor.class);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved similar kind of problem by specifying scope of my bean as `prototype` without using bean name. Below example explains my implementation:

Create your `Processor` class as shown below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@Scope("prototype")
public class Processor {
    private String typesToProcess;

    public Processor(String typesToProcess) {
        this.typesToProcess = typesToProcess;
    }

    public void process(String type) {
        if (typesToProcess.equals(type)) {
            // process
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `ApplicationContextAware` to generate beans at runtime:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ApplicationContextAwareImpl implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextAwareImpl.initApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    }

    private static void initApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextAwareImpl.context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return context.getBean(requiredType);
    }

    public static Processor getProcessor(String typesToProcess) {
        Processor processor = ApplicationContextAwareImpl.getBean(Processor.class);
        processor.setTypesToProcess(typesToProcess);

        return processor;
    }
}
```

Use `ApplicationContextAwareImpl.getProcessor()` method to generate beans programmatically:

```
Processor type1Processor = ApplicationContextAwareImpl.getProcessor("type1");
```